# Unintended Consequence of Rose and Finn's Quest

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

Finn and Rose's well-intended quest results in

> a code breaker being brought to The First Order who makes a deal and reveals technology used by The Resistance.

It seems a very ironic consequence; had they not departed,

> The remaining Resistance would have likely escaped.

As such, wouldn't the responsibility for The First Order's

> decimation of The Resistance and Luke's sacrificial death

ultimately fall on these two and their actions?  Is this addressed in the movie or perhaps mentioned by the directors as a potential long-term psychological consequence for the characters?

Comment: I think that’s a major theme in this movie: the unintended consequences of seemingly good actions. It’s not just this. There’s also Poe’s ill-fated bombing run in the beginning, Luke’s founding of a new Jedi academy, and possibly Rey’s attempt to persuade Kylo to abandon Snoke. Reaching a little further into supplementary materials, maybe even Leia and Han handing Kylo over to Luke for Jedi training.

Comment: @Adamant, perhaps as well Snoke's pushing Ren too far?  Was this theme ever mentioned explicitly by RJ?

Comment: Well, that’s maybe not a seemingly *good* action. ;)

Comment: Short answer: Yes.  It's their fault.  But, I think it's supposed to be part of Poe's "growing up story" to become a great leader one day, so since he *sent* them on this crazy mission, it's ultimately **his** responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with this question, in the movie, we clearly see the Resistance get away, although very narrowly. Also, Luke Skywalker was not going to provide them much help in the future, if he did decide to help. When the Hacker, Rose and Finn sneak out, they attract a lot of the troops on Snoke's Star Destroyer, ultimately, causing a distraction to help them get away. This act helped the Rebellion more than it hurt them. So this should not have many long term consequences, as it was an act of heroism.